# Is self-promotion allowed in a legitimate edit?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, self-promotion

I just encountered [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7855751) in the queue. The user suggesting the edit wants to add his own github project to those listed in an answer that has already received 10 upvotes.

I would normally pass this off as self-promotion, but at a glance, his library does appear to be thorough and contribute to the answer.

Should this edit be accepted?

Comment: No.  Reject that suggested edit.  It should be a comment.

Comment: Same edit here too:  http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7855780.  That's kind of shady, considering the edits are to either the most upvoted answer, or the accepted answer.  Also, [not the first time they've tried this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7466453) (and whee, I was there, too :D).  Don't think it's malicious, just not following SO's rules.

Comment: That answer consists mostly of links, would someone fancy editing it to include some details or pros and cons for each library ?

Comment: Question needs to be nuked from orbit.

Comment: @Will: The question may have received an answer with a library recommendation, but nothing in the question asked for off-site recommendations.  Closing it for that reason is 100% wrong.

Comment: @Ben "lemme drop my requirements on you to fulfill" is reason enough.  Questions like that imply links.  "Wrong or not, you're closing with me." - Ribbleclop

Comment: Meanwhile, a 36k user [made that edit, any way](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20504017/2)...

Comment: And now the whole post has been removed.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This edit isn't appropriate, but not because it's *self*-promotion. It's inappropriate because (in my opinion) it goes beyond the author's intent. These are the most common edits that I would consider to be staying within the author's intent:

- Fixing typos
- Improving formatting (e.g. code blocks)
- Correcting spelling and grammar
- Improving the phrasing in cases where the author has insufficient command of English to do so on their own
- Adding links to resources that the author has *already* mentioned

Generally speaking, anything else should be left to the author. Adding a link to a tool, website, or other resource that was not previously mentioned in the post at all falls in that latter category.

In cases where adding a link *is* an appropriate edit, I don't think it matters whether the person who makes that edit is affiliated with the target of the link or not.

---

Once it's been determined that the edit in question is inappropriate, then the issue comes up of whether to consider it spam. For *that* issue, the fact that the editor is adding their own link *is* highly relevant, as is the fact that they're doing it on multiple posts.

Comment: Any poster providing links that could be viewed as self-serving should be aware that their association to that link will make their post/edit be judged more stringently regardless on how altruistic their actual motivations are. True shill/hawker tag-teams post seemingly innocent questions that are almost instantly answered with questionable links by 'fan-boys'.

Comment: I've had it before where I have written a very short answer and it got accepted. A user with a lot of rep then editted my question and added a lot of new information. I am very grateful to that user cause the answer now adds more.

Comment: @Loko edited your _question_, or your _answer_? In any case, based on the brief description I would guess the high-rep user probably shouldn't have made that edit, but since you approve of it, it's fine. The first (or close to first) rule of editing is that the OP is the ultimate authority over what goes in their post.

Comment: @Loko I'm glad to find I'm not the only one who feels this way.

Comment: Meanwhile, a 36k user [made that edit, any way](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20504017/2)...

Comment: @Loko: Personally, I'm happy when someone edits my answers to add more information (except that if they don't leave a comment or write their own answer, I have nothing to upvote to show my approval…), but I'm a lot more wary of doing the same to other people's answers. I don't know which of those attitudes is more "right".

Comment: @DavidZ Answer. It was a great addition.

Comment: @abarnert I agree. I actually dont dare to do it myself. Maybe if I see an answer with very good intention and the code is working but it doesnt enough details, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @abarnert not everyone is as welcoming of edits as you are, and my sense is that, generally speaking, the "right" attitude on SE sites is one that respects people's right to control the _ideas_ that appear in their own answers. You can take your chances with an edit that goes beyond that, but I'd say it's somewhat discouraged unless and until the OP approves what you write.

Answer (score -16):

### Edit:

I've been convinced by comments below that this is not such a great idea after all. Leaving my answer up as an example of an incorrect way of thinking for future readers.

---

### Original:

I would call it not only acceptable, but the right way to do things.

Adding a comment may please the meta-readers more, but comments get lost when users are scanning answers for useful information.

By adding legitimate information to an answer, I believe you are improving the value of that page, and the site as a whole. This is the cleanest way of doing it.

In addition, the original author of the answer is going to be notified - they are in the best position to determine if the edit matches their original intent or not, and will be able to roll  it back if they disagree.

Comment: It's not correct to make it appear as though the question author is recommending this.  Highly inappropriate, actually.

Comment: SO requires disclosure of one's affiliation when promoting a product.  Slipping a link into someone else's post does not fulfill that requirement.

Comment: @Ben good point

Comment: @Matt in general I agree, but in this case the name on the github account makes it quite obvious. I just got the feeling it was innocent in this case. So far 11 disagree, giving !e some food for thought. I like meta giving us the chance to test our opinions for free.

Comment: That's true, but another edit by someone else will remove Jacek's user card from the answer and thus make it non-obvious again.  There's also the issue of his library possibly being crap and attracting downvotes to someone else's post.

Comment: The comment can suggest adding it to the post.  Unless the original answerer is long gone, the original answerer can fold it in if they choose.

Comment: @Matt "possibly being crap and attracting downvotes" - yes, I didn't even think about that at all.

Comment: Thanks for keeping your answer up despite the negative feedback. It's nice to have the dissenting opinion represented too.

Comment: @Brian I definitely think its part of the big picture. Especially since the comments to my answer have shown me the logic behind the accepted norm. (Plus its meta, its a discussion...)